# Open an element under a button when the button is clicked in React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, typescript

Having this design:

[image]

There is a table with some rows, when a row is clicked, that kebab button (3 vertical dots) is visible.

When the button is clicked it should open an element which has some data in it - in this case a list of actions.

The part with showing the kebab button is working:

```
{
  id: 'my-button',
  Cell: ({ cell }: CellProps<MyCell>) => {
    if (cell.row.index === selectedIndex) {
      return (
        <div>
          <Button
            icon={<ThreeDots />}
            onClick={toggleModal}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
    return <div></div>;
  }
}
```

when the row is clicked, the 3-dots button is visible. There is also a boolean which is initially set to false but toggles its value when the button is clicked (`toggleModal`).

But how can that element with the list added under the button?

Done something like:

```
{isModalOpened ? <div className='absolute'>test</div> : null}
```

Or maybe is there any online solution to fix this?

Comment: You can try MUI [menu component](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-menu/), check the first example

Comment: @Usama is there a way without using other libraries?

Comment: This [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/yeof1?file=/src/App.js) may help. You need to create `li` items and show them only when button is clicked, which can be done using state variable

Comment: just add an absolute element and position it as you needs, heres a simple one i made http://jsfiddle.net/rm48nzLo/28/

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, you just need to use:

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

Please check my demo below:

```js
function rowClick() {
  const status = document.getElementById("actions").style.display;
  document.getElementById("actions").style.display =
    status === "block" ? "none" : "block";
}

function btnClick(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  const status = document.getElementById("nav").style.display;
  document.getElementById("nav").style.display =
    status === "block" ? "none" : "block";
}
```

```css
.row {
  width: 80%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}
.actions {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
nav {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 10;
  background: white;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  min-width: 170px;
}
nav p {
  padding: 10px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  margin: 0;
}
nav p:last-child {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
.btn  {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: green;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='row' onclick="rowClick()">
  This is a row <div class="actions" id="actions"><span class="btn" onclick="btnClick(event)">⁝</span><nav id="nav"><p>Do this</p><p>Do that</p></nav></div></div>
```